# tc-server 2.9.2 Logfactory error

Tags: tomcat, logging, wrapper, tcserver

When Iuse the latest tcsever 2.9.2, I am getting this error.

`ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 | JVM exited while loading the application.
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       at org.apache.catalina.startup.BootstrapWrapper.(BootstrapWrapper.java:60)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2014/01/21 19:06:47 |       ... 1 more
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/01/21 19:06:52 | Launching a JVM...`

Please point me where I shd look to resolve this issue.

Tanuski wrapper main class (bootstrapwrapper  is causing this)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your server configuration, and add tomcat-juli.jar to the classpath, and it should work.

Comment: No, in batch file you use for starting tomcat (-classpath ...)

Comment: I am using tanuski wrapper, which loads the main class, the error is occuring there